# Rails 5 Devise not saving nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I am trying to use **configure_permitted_parameters** for saving nested attributes at signup. What I did

in routes

```
devise_for :students , controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Student Model:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :highlights

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :highlights #,:reject_if => proc { |a| a['name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Over ride registrations controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, :only => [:create]

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name ,:college_ids, highlights_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], adjectives_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy]) }
    end
end
```

In view

```
#highlights
  = f.simple_fields_for :highlights, (f.object.highlights.build unless f.object.highlights.present?) do |highlight|
    = render 'highlight_fields', f: highlight
  .example
    .col-xs-12
      = link_to_add_association f, :highlights, class:"btn btn-dark waves-effect waves-light" do
        i.icon.md-plus
        span.hidden-xs Add More Highlights
```

highlights partial

```
.highlight.nested-fields
  .example
    .col-md-11
      = f.input :name,required:true, wrapper: :base_input,input_html:{value: f.object.name }, label:'NAME', placeholder:'Name here'

    .col-sm-1
      h4.example-title &nbsp;
      = link_to_remove_association  f, class:'btn  btn-icon btn-flat btn-default red-600' do
        i.icon.md-delete
```

Now when I try to save than params I receive are

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"z+ue8ewIcnZY3OUFQI8sKq4yNbmc0Zi8w5Jdiioov6A3tWRxS9+r8lyqbOahzo+9ftWS06JtKBYDDyXLtOwAEQ==", "student"=><ActionController::Parameters {"first_name"=>"Muhammad", "last_name"=>"Iqbal", "email"=>"m.faisal.pucit@gmail.com", "password"=>"12345678", "password_confirmation"=>"12345678", "highlights_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"ada", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "adjectives_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "_destroy"=>"false"}}} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

But it's only saving first_name and last_name for student but not highlights.

What have I missed?

Call logs:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"z+ue8ewIcnZY3OUFQI8sKq4yNbmc0Zi8w5Jdiioov6A3tWRxS9+r8lyqbOahzo+9ftWS06JtKBYDDyXLtOwAEQ==", "student"=>{"first_name"=>"Muhammad", "last_name"=>"Iqbal", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "highlights_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"ada", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "adjectives_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}
```

Comment: can you show the log? do you see any error about unpermitted parameters? the docs shows a `keys` key when permitting the parameters https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: @arieljuod no message about this 
I added call logs in question

Comment: I mean the full log of the request, not just the parameters part. Also try using the syntax of the docs, you are permitting the parameters with a different syntax.

Comment: @arieljuod thanks a lot, syntax  from docs worked
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name ,:college_ids, highlights_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], adjectives_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy]])